# Where to find the latest version of the Vlocity_cme managed package?

Tags: managed-package, cicd, vlocity, energy-and-utilities, industry-cloud

Is there a way to, using bash script, to get the latest available Vlocity_cme package version ID? (`04t`).

The ID is part of this [page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=ind.comms__salesforce_industries_communications__media__and_energy_package_links.htm&type=5), but using wget you get an empty page, so that doesn't work.

Is there another way to get the latest package version ID?